# Make and populate a PySpark dataframe with columns as period_range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe like this

```
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|id_       | p      |d1        |  d2      |
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1       | A      |2018-09-26|2018-10-26|
|  2       | B      |2018-06-21|2018-07-19|
|  2       | B      |2018-08-13|2018-10-07|
|  2       | B      |2018-12-31|2019-02-27|
|  2       | B      |2019-05-28|2019-06-25|
|  3       |C       |2018-06-15|2018-07-13|
|  3       |C       |2018-08-15|2018-10-09|
|  3       |C       |2018-12-03|2019-03-12|
|  3       |C       |2019-05-10|2019-06-07|
| 4        | A      |2019-01-30|2019-03-01|
| 4        | A      |2019-05-30|2019-07-25|
| 5        |C       |2018-09-19|2018-10-17|
-------------------------------------------
```

From this I want to create and populate another Pyspark dataframe which have `n` columns ranging from `min(d1)` to `max(d2)` and each column is a date in that range.

I want to populate this dataframe with 1 and 0 for each row.

For row 1 I want populate all the days in the range min(d1 of row 1) to max(d1 of row 1) with `1` and rest columns with a `0`. Similarly for all the rows in the dataframe.

I was doing something like this in pandas for this purpose.

```
result = pd.DataFrame(data = 0, columns=pd.period_range(data['d1'].min(), data['d2'].max(), freq='D'), index=data.index)

for c in result.columns:
    result[c] = np.where((c.d2>=data.d1)&(c.d1 <= data.d2), 1, 0)
```

How to do the same in PySpark.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with list comprehension:

**UPDATE:** per request, adjusted `d1`, `d2` fields from StringType to DateType.

### Setup data, modules:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

#... skip the code to initialize SparkSession spark and df

# if d1 and d2 were read as String, convert them to Date using the following.
# Or if the data were already imported with explicit schema or inferSchema=True when running read.csv(), then skip the following:
df = df.withColumn('d1', F.to_date('d1')) \
       .withColumn('d2', F.to_date('d2'))

>>> df.show()
+---+---+----------+----------+
|id_|  p|        d1|        d2|
+---+---+----------+----------+
|  1|  A|2018-09-26|2018-10-26|
|  2|  B|2018-06-21|2018-07-19|
|  2|  B|2018-08-13|2018-10-07|
|  2|  B|2018-12-31|2019-02-27|
|  2|  B|2019-05-28|2019-06-25|
|  3|  C|2018-06-15|2018-07-13|
|  3|  C|2018-08-15|2018-10-09|
|  3|  C|2018-12-03|2019-03-12|
|  3|  C|2019-05-10|2019-06-07|
|  4|  A|2019-01-30|2019-03-01|
|  4|  A|2019-05-30|2019-07-25|
|  5|  C|2018-09-19|2018-10-17|
+---+---+----------+----------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id_: string (nullable = true)
 |-- p: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d1: date (nullable = true)
 |-- d2: date (nullable = true)
```

### Get min(d1) for `start_date` and max(d2) for `end_date`:

```
d = df.select(F.min('d1').alias('start_date'), F.max('d2').alias('end_date')).first()

>>> d
Row(start_date=datetime.date(2018, 6, 15), end_date=datetime.date(2019, 7, 25))
```

### Get a list of dates and convert them to Date

```
cols = [ c.to_timestamp().date() for c in pd.period_range(d.start_date, d.end_date, freq='D') ]

>>> cols
[datetime.date(2018, 6, 15),
 datetime.date(2018, 6, 16),
...
 datetime.date(2019, 7, 23),
 datetime.date(2019, 7, 24),
 datetime.date(2019, 7, 25)]
```

### Use list comprehension and when() function

Use list comprehension to iterate all dates in `cols`, `F.when(condition,1).otherwise(0)` to set up the column values and `str(c)` for the column names (alias):

```
result = df.select('id_', *[ F.when((df.d1 <= c)&(df.d2 >= c),1).otherwise(0).alias(str(c)) for c in cols ])

# check data in some columns
result.select('id_', str(d.start_date), '2019-01-01', str(d.end_date)).show()
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|id_|2018-06-15|2019-01-01|2019-07-25|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|         0|         1|         0|
|  2|         0|         0|         0|
|  3|         1|         0|         0|
|  3|         0|         0|         0|
|  3|         0|         1|         0|
|  3|         0|         0|         0|
|  4|         0|         0|         0|
|  4|         0|         0|         1|
|  5|         0|         0|         0|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can I have `DateType` column directly without making them `StringType`.?

Comment: @SreeramTP, updated and converted all String operations to use timestamp fields.

Comment: Cool. Looks awsome. I also want to retain the `id_, p` info somehow in the `result` dataframe. How to do that.? Sperate merging seems tedious to do

Comment: @SreeramTP, just add the 'id_' into the list of `df.select()`, check the updated post.

Comment: Code works as expected. But with increase in dates to be created it becomes painfully slow

Comment: Any method to speed up the process will be helpful

Comment: @SreeramTP, is it possible to convert these columns into a column of Sparse vectors instead of N columns(especially if you are working on some ML tasks)? Also, if you are using the spark 2.40+, we might try spark SQL builtin function `transform` + `sequence`. but I doubt that would get any big change on performance over the current solution.

Comment: Sparse columns won't serve my purpose.

Comment: My purpose is to find something like `presence` on each and every day. You can think something like marking attendence for each `id_` for those dates from `d1` to `d2`

Comment: @SreeramTP, what is the expected result dataframe based on the existing sample?  are you looking to group by `id_` and `p`, then find if the sum() is greater than 0 on columns containing all dates in the specified date_range?? what is the Spark version you are working on?

Comment: @jxc, how can only one column be auto-populated, such as have a min column and have a set value autopopulate for each row? I have a question [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787976/populating-column-in-dataframe-with-pyspark)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach (I have taken only few rows and small date ranges to print the output here)

- Identify min and max date (Please note that i have taken min from d1 and max form d2, but you can change if min d2 is less than min d1 for your data)
- Construct the struct, with dates as struct fields
- Populate the struct fields using udf
- Expand the struct by selecting struct.*

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import datetime

def fill_dates(d1, d2, start_date, no_of_date_cols):
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, '%Y-%m-%d')
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, '%Y-%m-%d')
    cols = {}
    for x in range(0, no_of_date_cols):
        col = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        if datetime.datetime.strptime(col, '%Y-%m-%d') >= d1 and datetime.datetime.strptime(col, '%Y-%m-%d') <= d2:
            cols[col] = 1
        else:
            cols[col] = 0
    return cols

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Filling_Dates_Cols") \
    .config("master", "local") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
                        [1, 'A', '2018-09-26', '2018-09-28'],
                        [2, 'B', '2018-09-20', '2018-09-22'],
                        [2, 'B', '2018-09-23', '2018-09-26'],
                        [3, 'C', '2018-09-15', '2018-09-26']
                        ], schema=['id', 'p', 'd1', 'd2'])

min_max_dates = df.select(
    F.min('d1').alias('min'),
    F.max('d2').alias('max')
).collect()[0]

min_date = min_max_dates[0]
max_date = min_max_dates[1]

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(min_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(max_date, '%Y-%m-%d')

no_of_date_cols = (d2 - d1).days + 1

schema = T.StructType()

for x in range(0, no_of_date_cols):
    new_col = (d1 + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    schema = schema.add(new_col, T.IntegerType())

fill_dates_udf = F.udf(fill_dates, schema)

df = df.withColumn(
    'dates',
    fill_dates_udf(F.col('d1'), F.col('d2'), F.lit(min_date), F.lit(no_of_date_cols))
)

df.select('id', 'p', 'd1', 'd2', 'dates.*').show()
```

which results in

```
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id|  p|        d1|        d2|2018-09-15|2018-09-16|2018-09-17|2018-09-18|2018-09-19|2018-09-20|2018-09-21|2018-09-22|2018-09-23|2018-09-24|2018-09-25|2018-09-26|2018-09-27|2018-09-28|
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|  A|2018-09-26|2018-09-28|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         1|         1|         1|
|  2|  B|2018-09-20|2018-09-22|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         1|         1|         1|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|  B|2018-09-23|2018-09-26|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         0|         1|         1|         1|         1|         0|         0|
|  3|  C|2018-09-15|2018-09-26|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         1|         0|         0|
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Works as expected. But Leads to `StackOverFlow` when the the dates to be made are huge.