# Populate month wise dataframe from two date columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe like this,

```
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|id_       | p      |d1        |  d2      |
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1       | A      |2018-09-26|2018-10-26|
|  2       | B      |2018-06-21|2018-07-19|
|  2       | B      |2018-08-13|2018-10-07|
|  2       | B      |2018-12-31|2019-02-27|
|  2       | B      |2019-05-28|2019-06-25|
|  3       |C       |2018-06-15|2018-07-13|
|  3       |C       |2018-08-15|2018-10-09|
|  3       |C       |2018-12-03|2019-03-12|
|  3       |C       |2019-05-10|2019-06-07|
| 4        | A      |2019-01-30|2019-03-01|
| 4        | B      |2019-05-30|2019-07-25|
| 5        |C       |2018-09-19|2018-10-17|
-------------------------------------------
```

From this dataframe I have to derive another dataframe which have n columns. Where each column is a month from `month(min(d1))` to `month(max(d2))`.

I want a in the derived dataframe for a row in the actual dataframe and the column values must be number of days in that month.

For example,

for first row, where `id_` is `1` and `p` is `A`, I want to get a row in the derived dataframe where column of `201809` with value `5` and column `201810` with value `26`.

For second row where `id_` is `2` and `p` is `B`, I want to get a row in the derived dataframe where column of `201806` should be `9` and `201807` should be `19`.

For the second last row, I want the columns `201905` filled with value `1`, column `201906` with value `30`, `201907` with `25`.

So basically, I want the dataframe to be populated such a way that, for each row in my original dataframe I have a row in the derived dataframe where the columns in the table that corresponds to the month should be filled, for the range min(d1) to max(d2) with value number of days that is covered in that particular month.

I am currently doing this in the hard way. I am making n columns, where columns range for dates from `min(d1) to max(d2)`. I am filling theses column with `1` and then melting the data and filtering based on `value`. Finally aggregating this dataframe to get my desired result, then selected the max valued `p`.

In codes,

```
d = df.select(F.min('d1').alias('d1'), F.max('d2').alias('d2')).first()

cols = [ c.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for c in pd.period_range(d.d1, d.d2, freq='D') ]

result = df.select('id_', 'p', *[ F.when((df.d1 <= c)&(df.d2 >= c), 1).otherwise(0).alias(c) for c in cols ])

melted_data = melt(result, id_vars=['id_','p'], value_vars=cols)

melted_data = melted_data.withColumn('Month', F.substring(F.regexp_replace('variable', '-', ''), 1, 6))

melted_data = melted_data.groupBy('id_', 'Month', 'p').agg(F.sum('value').alias('days'))

melted_data = melted_data.orderBy('id_', 'Month', 'days', ascending=[False, False, False])

final_data = melted_data.groupBy('id_', 'Month').agg(F.first('p').alias('p'))
```

This codes takes a lot of time to run in decent configurations. How can I improve this.?

How can I achieve this task in a more optimized manner.? Making every single date in the range dont seems to be the best solution.

A small sample of the needed output is shown below,

```
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
|id_|p  |201806    |201807    |201808    | 201809   | 201810|
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
| 1 | A |         0|        0 |         0|      4   | 26    |
| 2 | B |         9|        19|         0|      0   | 0     |
| 2 | B |         0|        0 |        18|      30  | 7     |
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: tl;dr , Little confuse on `month(min(d1))` to `month(max(d2))`. Do you want remaining days of that month? Would be great if you can you give output final dataset.

Comment: I will try to get a sample data and update the required result soon.

Comment: So I want to have n columns. Where first column is month(min(D1)) and second one is month(min(D1)) + 1 likewise last column being month(max(D2)). And each column should have how many days that particular entry is occupied in that month. For a row if D1 was 2018-01-01 and D2 was 2018-05-05 then for that row column 201801 should be 31 because it is on the roll from 2018-01-01 and passing the month. And for 201802 it should be 28, 201803 it should be 31 and so on. And for 201805 it will be 5. Because it was only till 5th of that month. And all other columns will be 0.

Comment: Got it, So in your sample dataset. Each row will have 201806 to 201907 as columns and each with days passed kind of numbers. Correct?

Comment: Yep. Exactly...

Comment: I have added a sample output needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's slowing down because of the `freq='D'` and multiple transformations on dataset.

Please try below:

**Edit 1: Update for the quarter**

**Edit 2: Per comment, the start date should be included in Final result**

**Edit 3: Per comment, Update for the daily**

1. Prepared data

```
#Imports
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
import pandas as pd

 df.show()
+---+---+----------+----------+
| id|  p|        d1|        d2|
+---+---+----------+----------+
|  1|  A|2018-09-26|2018-10-26|
|  2|  B|2018-06-21|2018-07-19|
|  2|  B|2018-08-13|2018-10-07|
|  2|  B|2018-12-31|2019-02-27|
|  2|  B|2019-05-28|2019-06-25|
|  3|  C|2018-06-15|2018-07-13|
|  3|  C|2018-08-15|2018-10-09|
|  3|  C|2018-12-03|2019-03-12|
|  3|  C|2019-05-10|2019-06-07|
|  4|  A|2019-01-30|2019-03-01|
|  4|  B|2019-05-30|2019-07-25|
|  5|  C|2018-09-19|2018-10-17|
|  5|  C|2019-05-16|2019-05-29| # --> Same month case
+---+---+----------+----------+
```

2. Get the min and max date from a dataset with month frequency `freq='M'`

```
d = df.select(f.min('d1').alias('min'), f.max('d2').alias('max')).first()
dates = pd.period_range(d.min, d.max, freq='M').strftime("%Y%m").tolist()
dates
['201806', '201807', '201808', '201809', '201810', '201811', '201812', '201901', '201902', '201903', '201904', '201905', '201906', '201907']
```

3. Now, Final Buesiness logic using spark date operators and functions

```
df1 = df.select('id', 
    'p', 
    'd1',
    'd2', *[ (when( (f.trunc(df.d1, "month") == f.trunc(df.d2, "month")) & (f.to_date(f.lit(c),'yyyyMM') == f.trunc(df.d1, "month"))
                        , f.datediff(df.d2 , df.d1) +1 ) # Same month ((Last day - First dat) + 1
        .when(f.to_date(f.lit(c),'yyyyMM') == f.trunc(df.d1, "month") , 
                        f.datediff(f.last_day(f.to_date(f.lit(c),'yyyyMM')) , df.d1) +1 ) # d1 date (Last day - current day)
        .when(f.to_date(f.lit(c),'yyyyMM') == f.trunc(df.d2, "month") , 
                    f.datediff(df.d2, f.to_date(f.lit(c),'yyyyMM')) +1 ) # d2 date (Currentday - Firstday) 
        .when(f.to_date(f.lit(c),'yyyyMM').between(f.trunc(df.d1, "month"), df.d2), 
                    f.dayofmonth(f.last_day(f.to_date(f.lit(c),'yyyyMM')))) # Between date (Total days in month)
        ).otherwise(0) # Rest of the months (0)
    .alias(c) for c in dates ])

df1.show()
+---+---+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id|  p|        d1|        d2|201806|201807|201808|201809|201810|201811|201812|201901|201902|201903|201904|201905|201906|201907|
+---+---+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1|  A|2018-09-26|2018-10-26|     0|     0|     0|     5|    26|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|2018-06-21|2018-07-19|    10|    19|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|2018-08-13|2018-10-07|     0|     0|    19|    30|     7|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|2018-12-31|2019-02-27|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     1|    31|    27|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|2019-05-28|2019-06-25|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     4|    25|     0|
|  3|  C|2018-06-15|2018-07-13|    16|    13|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|2018-08-15|2018-10-09|     0|     0|    17|    30|     9|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|2018-12-03|2019-03-12|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|    29|    31|    28|    12|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|2019-05-10|2019-06-07|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|    22|     7|     0|
|  4|  A|2019-01-30|2019-03-01|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     2|    28|     1|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  4|  B|2019-05-30|2019-07-25|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     2|    30|    25|
|  5|  C|2018-09-19|2018-10-17|     0|     0|     0|    12|    17|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  5|  C|2019-05-16|2019-05-29|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|    14|     0|     0|
+---+---+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

**Edit 2: Update for the quarter range:**

***Note:*** Taking quarter date range dictionary from **@jxc's** answer. We are more interested in the optimal solution here. @jxc has done an excellent job and no point of reinventing the wheel unless there is a performance issue.

Create date range dictionary :

```
q_dates = dict([
    (str(c), [ c.to_timestamp().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") ,(c.to_timestamp() + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
     ]) for c in pd.period_range(d.min, d.max, freq='Q')
])


# {'2018Q2': ['2018-04-01', '2018-06-30'], 
# '2018Q3': ['2018-07-01', '2018-09-30'], 
# '2018Q4': ['2018-10-01', '2018-12-31'], 
# '2019Q1': ['2019-01-01', '2019-03-31'], 
# '2019Q2': ['2019-04-01', '2019-06-30'], 
# '2019Q3': ['2019-07-01', '2019-09-30']}
```

Now Apply business logic on quarters.

```
df1 = df.select('id', 
    'p', 
    'd1',
    'd2', 
    *[(when( (df.d1.between(q_dates[c][0], q_dates[c][1])) & (f.trunc(df.d1, "month") == f.trunc(df.d2, "month")), 
        f.datediff(df.d2 , df.d1) +1 ) # Same month ((Last day - start day) +1 )
    .when(df.d1.between(q_dates[c][0], q_dates[c][1]), 
        f.datediff(f.to_date(f.lit(q_dates[c][1])), df.d1) +1) # Min date , remaining days (Last day of quarter - Min day)
    .when(df.d2.between(q_dates[c][0], q_dates[c][1]), 
        f.datediff(df.d2, f.to_date(f.lit(q_dates[c][0]))) +1 ) # Max date , remaining days (Max day - Start day of quarter )
    .when(f.to_date(f.lit(q_dates[c][0])).between(df.d1, df.d2), 
        f.datediff(f.to_date(f.lit(q_dates[c][1])), f.to_date(f.lit(q_dates[c][0]))) +1) # All remaining days
    ).otherwise(0)
    .alias(c) for c in q_dates ])

df1.show()
+---+---+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id|  p|        d1|        d2|2018Q2|2018Q3|2018Q4|2019Q1|2019Q2|2019Q3|
+---+---+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1|  A|2018-09-26|2018-10-26|     0|     5|    26|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|2018-06-21|2018-07-19|    10|    19|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|2018-08-13|2018-10-07|     0|    49|     7|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|2018-12-31|2019-02-27|     0|     0|     1|    58|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|2019-05-28|2019-06-25|     0|     0|     0|     0|    34|     0|
|  3|  C|2018-06-15|2018-07-13|    16|    13|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|2018-08-15|2018-10-09|     0|    47|     9|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|2018-12-03|2019-03-12|     0|     0|    29|    71|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|2019-05-10|2019-06-07|     0|     0|     0|     0|    52|     0|
|  4|  A|2019-01-30|2019-03-01|     0|     0|     0|    61|     0|     0|
|  4|  B|2019-05-30|2019-07-25|     0|     0|     0|     0|    32|    25|
|  5|  C|2018-09-19|2018-10-17|     0|    12|    17|     0|     0|     0|
|  5|  C|2019-05-16|2019-05-29|     0|     0|     0|     0|    14|     0|
+---+---+----------+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

**Edit 3: Per comment, Update for the daily**

Since here evaluations are more, need to careful in terms of performance.

***Approach 1 : Dataframe/Dataset***

Get Date list in `yyyy-MM-dd` format but as string

```
df_dates = pd.period_range(d.min, d.max, freq='D').strftime("%Y-%m-%d").tolist()
```

Now the business logic is quite simple. It's either 1 or 0

```
df1 = df.select('id'
    , 'p'
    , 'd1'
    ,'d2'
    , *[ (when(f.lit(c).between (df.d1, df.d2),1)) # For date rabge 1
        .otherwise(0) # For rest of days
        .alias(c) for c in df_dates ])

df1.show()

+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id|  p|        d1|        d2|2018-06-15|2018-06-16|2018-06-17| # and so on....
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|  A|2018-09-26|2018-10-26|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|  B|2018-06-21|2018-07-19|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|  B|2018-08-13|2018-10-07|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|  B|2018-12-31|2019-02-27|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|  B|2019-05-28|2019-06-25|         0|         0|         0|
|  3|  C|2018-06-15|2018-07-13|         1|         1|         1|
|  3|  C|2018-08-15|2018-10-09|         0|         0|         0|
|  3|  C|2018-12-03|2019-03-12|         0|         0|         0|
|  3|  C|2019-05-10|2019-06-07|         0|         0|         0|
|  4|  A|2019-01-30|2019-03-01|         0|         0|         0|
|  4|  B|2019-05-30|2019-07-25|         0|         0|         0|
|  5|  C|2018-09-19|2018-10-17|         0|         0|         0|
|  5|  C|2019-05-16|2019-05-29|         0|         0|         0|
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
# Due to answer character limit unable to give the result.
```

***Approach 2: RDD evaluations***

Get Date list as a `date object`

```
rdd_dates = [ c.to_timestamp().date() for c in pd.period_range(d.min, d.max, freq='D') ]
```

Use `map` from `rdd`

```
df1 = df \
.rdd \
.map(lambda x : tuple([x.id, x.p, x.d1, x.d2 , *[ 1 if ( x.d1 <= c <=x.d2) else  0 for c in rdd_dates]])) \
.toDF(df.columns + [ c.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for c in rdd_dates])

df1.show()

+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id|  p|        d1|        d2|2018-06-15|2018-06-16|2018-06-17| # and so on....
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|  A|2018-09-26|2018-10-26|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|  B|2018-06-21|2018-07-19|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|  B|2018-08-13|2018-10-07|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|  B|2018-12-31|2019-02-27|         0|         0|         0|
|  2|  B|2019-05-28|2019-06-25|         0|         0|         0|
|  3|  C|2018-06-15|2018-07-13|         1|         1|         1|
|  3|  C|2018-08-15|2018-10-09|         0|         0|         0|
|  3|  C|2018-12-03|2019-03-12|         0|         0|         0|
|  3|  C|2019-05-10|2019-06-07|         0|         0|         0|
|  4|  A|2019-01-30|2019-03-01|         0|         0|         0|
|  4|  B|2019-05-30|2019-07-25|         0|         0|         0|
|  5|  C|2018-09-19|2018-10-17|         0|         0|         0|
|  5|  C|2019-05-16|2019-05-29|         0|         0|         0|
+---+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will get back regarding the efficiency. At the same time can I extend this to work for quarter instead of months.?

Comment: @SreeramTP: Absolutely, setting `freq='Q'` will be a way to go. Let me know if this gives better performance, we can extend the same.

Comment: I have tested with minimal configuration and the solution is running fine.

Comment: Also, Is there a way to fasten up with the `freq=D` .? I need to create for some other part of my application. See my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57070594/make-and-populate-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-columns-as-period-range/57083324?noredirect=1#comment101901114_57083324

Comment: @SreeramTP: Please try a different approach than @jxc's. here only difference is how we are building the SQL for a spark to parse. I would be surprised if @jxc and this approach give different performances. Once you validate for Month and quarter we can go for `freq=D`. AFAIK, 1000 columns and a few thousands of rows can be handled with these approaches (Above and @jxc's).

Comment: Months and Quaters are running fine both on local and in cluster within expected time.

Comment: I am getting a mismatch when the d1 is last day of the month. Something like `2019-05-31`. I want to have `1` in the month `201905` whereas I am getting `0` in this case

Comment: Great...! Clarification, For rest of the dates of d1 we have remaining days of that month. Like for row 1 we populated 4 as (30-26). It won’t be consistent if we keep 1, Do you still want 1 if d1 is last day of month?

Comment: What if we subtract from start of next month.? subtract from `F.last + 1`

Comment: If you always want +1 then we can add like we are adding for last month calculation (d2 dated comment in ans). Sorry replying from cell so won’t be able to do formatting in comments.

Comment: That will do, we can find the difference from 1st of next month rather than the last of current month.

Comment: Ok, so you want 5 for row#1 as well?

Comment: Yeah, I was going through it. I think this will server my purpose. Can you also update to keep the value as `1` if the `d1` is the last date directly. (no need to subtract from 1st of next month)

Comment: @SreeramTP : No need, This logic will give `1` if start date is last day of the month.

Comment: we are missing a case if both d1 and d2 fall in same month I guess. See chat for detailed info

Comment: @SMaZ can you take a look at this question of mine .? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941836/find-min-and-max-range-with-a-combination-of-column-values-in-pyspark

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, your problem can be simplified using some Spark SQL tricks:

```
# get start_date and end_date 
d = df.select(F.min('d1').alias('start_date'), F.max('d2').alias('end_date')).first()

# get a list of month strings (using the first day of the month) between d.start_date and d.end_date
mrange = [ c.strftime("%Y-%m-01") for c in pd.period_range(d.start_date, d.end_date, freq='M') ]
#['2018-06-01',
# '2018-07-01',
# ....
# '2019-06-01',
# '2019-07-01']
```

Write the following Spark SQL snippet to count the number of days in each month, where `{0}` will be replaced by the month strings(i.e. "2018-06-01"), and `{1}` will be replaced by column names(i.e. "201806").

```
stmt = '''
    IF(d2 < "{0}" OR d1 > LAST_DAY("{0}")
     , 0
     , DATEDIFF(LEAST(d2, LAST_DAY("{0}")), GREATEST(d1, TO_DATE("{0}")))   
           + IF(d1 BETWEEN "{0}" AND LAST_DAY("{0}"), 0, 1)
    ) AS `{1}`
'''
```

This SQL snippet does the following, assumed `m` is the month string:

- if (d1, d2) is out of range, i.e. `d1 > last_day(m) or d2 < m`, then return 0
- otherwise, we calculate the `datediff()` between `LEAST(d2, LAST_DAY(m))` and `GREATEST(d1, m)`.
- Notice there is an `1` day offset in calculating the above `datediff()`. it only exists when `d1` is NOT in the current month, i.e. `between(m, LAST_DAY(m))`

We can then calculate the new columns using `selectExpr` and this SQL snippet:

```
df_new = df.withColumn('d1', F.to_date('d1')) \
           .withColumn('d2', F.to_date('d2')) \
           .selectExpr(
                 'id_'
               , 'p'
               , *[ stmt.format(m, m[:7].replace('-','')) for m in mrange ]
         )

df_new.show()
+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|id_|  p|201806|201807|201808|201809|201810|201811|201812|201901|201902|201903|201904|201905|201906|201907|
+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1|  A|     0|     0|     0|     4|    26|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|     9|    19|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|     0|     0|    18|    30|     7|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|    31|    27|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     3|    25|     0|
|  3|  C|    15|    13|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|     0|     0|    16|    30|     9|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|    28|    31|    28|    12|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|    21|     7|     0|
|  4|  A|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     1|    28|     1|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  4|  B|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     1|    30|    25|
|  5|  C|     0|     0|     0|    11|    17|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|     0|
+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

---

**Edit-1: About the Quarterly list**

Per your comment, I modified the SQL snippet so that you can extend it into more named date ranges. see below: `{0}` will be replaced by range_start_date, and `{1}` by range_end_date and `{2}` by range_name:

```
stmt = '''
    IF(d2 < "{0}" OR d1 > "{1}"
     , 0
     , DATEDIFF(LEAST(d2, TO_DATE("{1}")), GREATEST(d1, TO_DATE("{0}")))
           + IF(d1 BETWEEN "{0}" AND "{1}", 0, 1)
    ) AS `{2}`
'''
```

Create a dictionary using quarter name as keys and a list of corresponding start_date and end_date as values: (this part is a pure python or pandas problem)

```
range_dict = dict([
    (str(c), [ c.to_timestamp().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
              ,(c.to_timestamp() + pd.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
     ]) for c in pd.period_range(d.start_date, d.end_date, freq='Q')
])
#{'2018Q2': ['2018-04-01', '2018-06-30'],
# '2018Q3': ['2018-07-01', '2018-09-30'],
# '2018Q4': ['2018-10-01', '2018-12-31'],
# '2019Q1': ['2019-01-01', '2019-03-31'],
# '2019Q2': ['2019-04-01', '2019-06-30'],
# '2019Q3': ['2019-07-01', '2019-09-30']}

df_new = df.withColumn('d1', F.to_date('d1')) \
           .withColumn('d2', F.to_date('d2')) \
           .selectExpr(
             'id_'
           , 'p'
           , *[ stmt.format(range_dict[n][0], range_dict[n][1], n) for n in sorted(range_dict.keys()) ]
        )

df_new.show()
+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|id_|  p|2018Q2|2018Q3|2018Q4|2019Q1|2019Q2|2019Q3|
+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1|  A|     0|     4|    26|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|     9|    19|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|     0|    48|     7|     0|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|     0|     0|     0|    58|     0|     0|
|  2|  B|     0|     0|     0|     0|    28|     0|
|  3|  C|    15|    13|     0|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|     0|    46|     9|     0|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|     0|     0|    28|    71|     0|     0|
|  3|  C|     0|     0|     0|     0|    28|     0|
|  4|  A|     0|     0|     0|    30|     0|     0|
|  4|  B|     0|     0|     0|     0|    31|    25|
|  5|  C|     0|    11|    17|     0|     0|     0|
+---+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

**Edit-2: Regarding the Segmentation errors**

I tested the code with a sample dataframe of 56K rows (see below), everything ran well under my testing environment (VM, Centos 7.3, 1 CPU and 2GB RAM, spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7 run on local mode in a docker container. this is far below any production environment). Thus I doubt if it was from the Spark version issue? I rewrote the same code logic by using two different approaches: one is using only Spark SQL(with TempView etc) and another is using pure dataframe API functions(similar to @SMaZ's approach). I'd like to see if any of these could run through your environment and data. BTW. I think, given most of the fields are numeric, 1M rows + 100 columns should not be very huge in terms of big data projects.

Also, please do make sure if there exists missing data (null for d1/d2) or incorrectly data issues (i.e. `d1 > d2`) and adjust the code to handle such issues if needed.

```
# sample data-set
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

N = 560000
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'id_': sorted(np.random.choice(range(100),N))
      , 'p': np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMN'),N)
      , 'd1': sorted(np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2016-06-30','2019-06-30',freq='D'),N))
      , 'n': np.random.choice(list(map(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(days=x), range(300))),N)
})
df1['d2'] = df1['d1'] + df1['n']
df = spark.createDataFrame(df1)
df.printSchema()                                                                                                    
#root
# |-- id_: long (nullable = true)
# |-- p: string (nullable = true)
# |-- d1: timestamp (nullable = true)
# |-- n: long (nullable = true)
# |-- d2: timestamp (nullable = true)

# get the overall date-range of dataset
d = df.select(F.min('d1').alias('start_date'), F.max('d2').alias('end_date')).first()
#Row(start_date=datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 20, 0), end_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 22, 20, 0))

# range_dict for the month data
range_dict = dict([
    (c.strftime('%Y%m'), [ c.to_timestamp().date()
              ,(c.to_timestamp() + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd()).date()
     ]) for c in pd.period_range(d.start_date, d.end_date, freq='M')
])
#{'201606': [datetime.date(2016, 6, 1), datetime.date(2016, 6, 30)],
# '201607': [datetime.date(2016, 7, 1), datetime.date(2016, 7, 31)],
# '201608': [datetime.date(2016, 8, 1), datetime.date(2016, 8, 31)],
# ....
# '202003': [datetime.date(2020, 3, 1), datetime.date(2020, 3, 31)],
# '202004': [datetime.date(2020, 4, 1), datetime.date(2020, 4, 30)]}
```

### Method-1: Using Spark SQL:

```
# create TempView `df_table`
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df_table')

# SQL snippet to calculate new column
stmt = '''
     IF(d2 < "{0}" OR d1 > "{1}"
      , 0
      , DATEDIFF(LEAST(d2, to_date("{1}")), GREATEST(d1, to_date("{0}")))
           + IF(d1 BETWEEN "{0}" AND "{1}", 0, 1)
     ) AS `{2}`
'''

# set up the SQL field list
sql_fields_list = [
      'id_'
    , 'p'
    , *[ stmt.format(range_dict[n][0], range_dict[n][1], n) for n in sorted(range_dict.keys()) ]
]
# create SQL statement
sql_stmt = 'SELECT {} FROM df_table'.format(', '.join(sql_fields_list))

# run the Spark SQL:
df_new = spark.sql(sql_stmt)
```

### Method-2: Using dataframe API functions:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, greatest, least, lit, datediff

df_new = df.select(
      'id_'
    , 'p'
    , *[
         when((col('d2') < range_dict[n][0]) | (col('d1') > range_dict[n][1]), 0).otherwise(
                datediff(least('d2', lit(range_dict[n][1])), greatest('d1', lit(range_dict[n][0])))
                    + when(col('d1').between(range_dict[n][0], range_dict[n][1]), 0).otherwise(1)
            ).alias(n)
            for n in sorted(range_dict.keys())
       ]
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can this solution be extended to work for quarters of the year ?

Comment: @SreeramTP, updated the answer, I believe you can extend it to yearly, weekly etc using a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried the code with a few thousand rows and I am getting a StackOverFlow error.

Comment: @SreeramTP, can you add more details with the errors, in which part it yielded the error? or can you send me the number of rows and the `d.start_date`, `d.end_date` when you get this error? I will be out in about 30 minutes and will check this back later today.

Comment: `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o377.showString.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.extract16BitValue(CodeContext.java:720)
 at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:561)
 at org.codehaus.janino.CodeContext.flowAnalysis(CodeContext.java:557)` is the first few lines of the error

Comment: `datetime.date(2016, 6, 30)` is the `start_date` and `datetime.date(2019, 6, 30)` is the `end_date`. Number of rows is `56000`. And this is a sample data only.

Comment: I got error while I tried to a `.show(10)`. For the Quater solution the code is running fine. I guess expanding those many columns (3*12) is filling JVM stack space up for the months code

Comment: @jxc:  I have used your dictionary code for my answer. Please let me know if that's not ok, I can take it down and we can give `when` approach in your answer. Thanks. I saw your code here and a couple of other places. Amazing work...!

Comment: @SMaZ, no problem.:)

Comment: @SreeramTP, I tested the code with a sample dataframe containing 5.6K and 56K rows, both running well w/o the Segmentation error. I guess it was from a Spark version issue. I've added two more methods using the same logic but with Spark SQL and Dataframe API respectively and will update my post next.

Comment: I am running spark 2.4 in my local and 2.3.1 on my cluster. I am getting same issue. But interestingly `.collect()` and `.toPandas()` works fine both places but `.show()` don't. And the time taken is almost double with the other approch

Comment: @jxc I tried both the approaches. I made sure d1 <= d2 and there are no nulls in `d1` and `d2`. Both approaches failes with `.show()` but works fine with `.collect()` and `.toPandas()`. I wonder what is happening. The run time is almost double in my local compared with @SMaZ 's answer. I will update the time on cluster soon.

Comment: @SreeramTP, I am not able to reproduce the segmentation errors running `df_new.show()` from my VM (all default spark_configs) with the above sample data 560,000 rows (10 times than what you mentioned). driver memory usually could be the source but since it worked in @SMaZ's solution, I don't think it's the reason here. Originally I thought it could be old version spark using a different execution plan, but since you are running the same Spark version as mine, this should be cleared. Anyway, good luck for your task, I will not update my solution going forward. have a good week start.:)

Comment: Thanks and I really appreciate your time and contribution. I will keep you posted with testing. Have a great week ahead :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **avoid pandas completely (which brings the data back to driver)** then a pure pyspark based solution can be:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf

# Assumption made: your dataframe's name is : sample_data and has id, p, d1, d2 columns.

# Add month and days left column using pyspark functions
# I have kept a row id as well just to ensure that if you have duplicates in your data on the keys then it would still be able to handle it - no obligations though
data = sample_data.select("id", "p", 
                          psf.monotonically_increasing_id().alias("row_id"),
                          psf.date_format("d2", 'YYYYMM').alias("d2_month"),
                          psf.dayofmonth("d2").alias("d2_id"),
                          psf.date_format("d1", 'YYYYMM').alias("d1_month"),
                          psf.datediff(psf.last_day("d1"), sample_data["d1"]).alias("d1_id"))

data.show(5, False)
```

Result:

```
+---+---+-----------+--------+-----+--------+-----+
|id |p  |row_id     |d2_month|d2_id|d1_month|d1_id|
+---+---+-----------+--------+-----+--------+-----+
|1  |A  |8589934592 |201810  |26   |201809  |4    |
|2  |B  |25769803776|201807  |19   |201806  |9    |
|2  |B  |34359738368|201810  |7    |201808  |18   |
|2  |B  |51539607552|201902  |27   |201912  |0    |
|2  |B  |60129542144|201906  |25   |201905  |3    |
+---+---+-----------+--------+-----+--------+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Then you can split the dataframe and pivot it:

```py
####
# Create two separate dataframes by pivoting on d1_month and d2_month
####
df1 = data.groupby(["id", "p", "row_id"]).pivot("d1_month").max("d1_id")
df2 = data.groupby(["id", "p", "row_id"]).pivot("d2_month").max("d2_id")

df1.show(5, False), df2.show(5, False)
```

Result:

```
+---+---+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|id |p  |row_id      |201806|201808|201809|201812|201901|201905|201912|
+---+---+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|3  |C  |85899345920 |null  |16    |null  |null  |null  |null  |null  |
|2  |B  |51539607552 |null  |null  |null  |null  |null  |null  |0     |
|3  |C  |77309411328 |15    |null  |null  |null  |null  |null  |null  |
|3  |C  |103079215104|null  |null  |null  |28    |null  |null  |null  |
|4  |A  |128849018880|null  |null  |null  |null  |1     |null  |null  |
+---+---+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
only showing top 5 rows

+---+---+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|id |p  |row_id      |201807|201809|201810|201902|201903|201906|201907|
+---+---+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|3  |C  |85899345920 |null  |null  |9     |null  |null  |null  |null  |
|2  |B  |51539607552 |null  |null  |null  |27    |null  |null  |null  |
|3  |C  |77309411328 |13    |null  |null  |null  |null  |null  |null  |
|3  |C  |103079215104|null  |null  |null  |null  |12    |null  |null  |
|4  |A  |128849018880|null  |null  |null  |null  |1     |null  |null  |
+---+---+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Join back and get your result:

```py
result = df1.join(df2, on=["id", "p","row_id"])\
            .select([psf.coalesce(df1[x_], df2[x_]).alias(x_)
                     if (x_ in df1.columns) and (x_ in df2.columns) else x_
                     for x_ in set(df1.columns + df2.columns)])\
            .orderBy("row_id").drop("row_id")

result.na.fill(0).show(5, False)
```

Result:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---+
|201906|201907|201912|201901|201810|p  |201812|201905|201902|201903|201809|201808|201807|201806|id |
+------+------+------+------+------+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---+
|0     |0     |0     |0     |26    |A  |0     |0     |0     |0     |4     |0     |0     |0     |1  |
|0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |B  |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |19    |9     |2  |
|0     |0     |0     |0     |7     |B  |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |18    |0     |0     |2  |
|0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |B  |0     |0     |27    |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |2  |
|25    |0     |0     |0     |0     |B  |0     |3     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |0     |2  |
+------+------+------+------+------+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```