# Find min and max range with a combination of column values in PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe like this,

```
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|id_       | p      |d1        |  d2      |
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1       | A      |2018-09-26|2018-10-26|
|  2       | B      |2018-06-21|2018-07-19|
|  2       | C      |2018-07-13|2018-10-07|
|  2       | B      |2018-12-31|2019-02-27|
|  2       | A      |2019-01-28|2019-06-25|
-------------------------------------------
```

From this dataframe I have to make a dataframe like this,

```
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|id_       | q      |d1        |  d2      |
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1       | A      |2018-09-26|2018-10-26|
|  2       | B      |2018-06-21|2018-07-12|
|  2       | B C    |2018-07-13|2018-07-19|
|  2       | C      |2018-07-20|2019-10-07|
|  2       | B      |2018-12-31|2019-01-27|
|  2       | B A    |2019-01-28|2019-02-27|
|  2       | A      |2019-02-28|2019-06-25|
-------------------------------------------
```

It is something like, finding which values of `p` are present in the data for a particular `id_` from when to when. If there are multiple `p` in a same day then both should be present in the data, seperated by a space.

I tried to do this is by creating each and every dates in the range `min(d1)` and `max(d2)` and filling them accordingly. From that dataframe, after some melting and grouping I can get the desired result.

But the process takes very long time and is very inefficient.

I am looking for an efficient method for performing this task.

I can also have more complex cases of overlap, ie overlap among more than two p-values.

See a sample data below,

```
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|id_       | p      |d1        |  d2      |
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1       | A      |2018-09-26|2018-10-26|
|  2       | B      |2018-06-21|2018-07-19|
|  2       | C      |2018-06-27|2018-07-07|
|  2       | A      |2018-07-02|2019-02-27|
|  2       | A      |2019-03-28|2019-06-25|
-------------------------------------------
```

This must be converted to,

```
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|id_       | q      |d1        |  d2      |
+----------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1       | A      |2018-09-26|2018-10-26|
|  2       | B      |2018-06-21|2018-06-26|
|  2       | B C    |2018-06-27|2018-07-01|
|  2       | B C A  |2018-07-02|2018-07-07|
|  2       | A B    |2018-07-08|2018-07-19|
|  2       | A      |2018-07-20|2019-02-27|
|  2       | A      |2019-03-28|2019-06-25|
-------------------------------------------
```

Order of individual items in the q doesn't matter. ie either if A, B and C are in overlap. It can either be shown as A B C, or B C A or A C B so on.

I am also adding an edge case that is hard to comeby, that is `d2 == lead(d1).over(window)`. In this case it can be safely assumed, the `p` values are different. ie `p != lead(p).over(window)`.

```
+---+---+----------+----------+
|id_| p |    d1    | d2       |
+---+---+----------+----------+
|100| 12|2013-10-16|2014-01-17|
|100| 12|2014-01-20|2014-04-15|
|100| 12|2014-04-22|2014-05-19|
|100| 12|2014-05-22|2014-06-19|
|100| 12|2014-07-23|2014-09-18|
|100| 12|2014-09-23|2014-12-18|
|100| 12|2014-12-20|2015-01-16|
|100| 12|2015-01-23|2015-02-19|
|100| 12|2015-02-21|2015-04-20|
|100| 7 |2015-04-20|2015-05-17|
|100| 7 |2015-05-19|2015-06-15|
|100| 7 |2015-06-18|2015-09-01|
|100| 7 |2015-09-09|2015-11-26|
+---+---+----------+----------+
```

In the above data, 4th and 5th row from the bottom shows the case. In this case the expected result is,

```
+---+-----+----------+----------+
|id_| p   | d1       | d2       |
+---+-----+----------+----------+
|100| 12  |2013-10-16|2014-01-17|
|100| 12  |2014-01-20|2014-04-15|
|100| 12  |2014-04-22|2014-05-19|
|100| 12  |2014-05-22|2014-06-19|
|100| 12  |2014-07-23|2014-09-18|
|100| 12  |2014-09-23|2014-12-18|
|100| 12  |2014-12-20|2015-01-16|
|100| 12  |2015-01-23|2015-02-19|
|100| 12  |2015-02-21|2015-04-19|
|100| 12 7|2015-04-20|2015-04-20|
|100| 7   |2015-04-21|2015-05-17|
|100| 7   |2015-05-19|2015-06-15|
|100| 7   |2015-06-18|2015-09-01|
|100| 7   |2015-09-09|2015-11-26|
+---+-----+----------+----------+
```

Another example for the same case is given below,

```
+---+---+----------+----------+
|id_| p | d1       | d2       |
+---+---+----------+----------+
|101| 12|2015-02-24|2015-03-23|
|101| 12|2015-04-01|2015-05-19|
|101| 12|2015-05-29|2015-06-25|
|101| 12|2015-07-03|2015-07-30|
|101| 12|2015-09-02|2015-09-29|
|101| 12|2015-10-02|2015-10-29|
|101| 9 |2015-10-29|2015-11-11|
|101| 9 |2015-11-25|2015-12-22|
+---+---+----------+----------+
```

And the expected result for the same is,

```
+---+-----+----------+----------+
|id_| q   | d1       | d2       |
+---+-----+----------+----------+
|101| 12  |2015-02-24|2015-03-23|
|101| 12  |2015-04-01|2015-05-19|
|101| 12  |2015-05-29|2015-06-25|
|101| 12  |2015-07-03|2015-07-30|
|101| 12  |2015-09-02|2015-09-29|
|101| 12  |2015-10-02|2015-10-28|
|101| 12 9|2015-10-29|2015-10-29|
|101| 9   |2015-10-30|2015-11-11|
|101| 9   |2015-11-25|2015-12-22|
+---+---+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi - What is dataset size?

Comment: Some Million rows. Less than a Billion

Comment: And please note the combination can be among more than two p values. Like A B C or A B C D so on

Comment: @SreeramTP, code adjusted to reflect the logic to set boundaries discussed in the chat/comments. please review and let me know for any problems. also, this will slower than the previous code due to added String operations.

Comment: @SreeramTP It looks something which can be preprocessed using the first version of my post with some modification on testing-conditions before using the code-logic in my post.

Comment: What exact preprocessing.? Can you make the update.? I thought about separating out those rows and dealing with them separately and merging back. Which is kinda inefficient.

Comment: @SreeramTP just added d1==d2 in the code to create df_drange and df1, this was skipped in the older codes. No need pre/post processings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Based on OP's comments and update, since any number of overlapping might happen, I think a dataframe-JOIN is probably the most straightforward way. Below is a completely new solution I tested on Spark 2.4.0 (array_join, transform, sequence etc. require Spark 2.4+):

**Update-2:** Per discussion in the comments/chat, I've added the code-logic to set up the boundaries for each `drange(d1, d2)` on how/when to adjust d1/d2, a new `flag` field is required in `df_drange` to complete this logic. details see below **`Set up boundaries`** section

**Update-3:** adjusted code to handle when `(d1 == d2)` in df_drange. originally removed such cases.

### Setup the data:

**Note:** I added df2 with d1 and d2 converted to DateType(), while the original df keeps two fields as StringType() since we need some concatenation operations.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lead, expr, to_date, collect_set, array_sort, array_join, broadcast

df = spark.createDataFrame([
      (1, 'A', '2018-09-26', '2018-10-26')
    , (2, 'B', '2018-06-21', '2018-07-19')
    , (2, 'C', '2018-06-27', '2018-07-07')
    , (2, 'A', '2018-07-02', '2019-02-27')
    , (2, 'A', '2019-03-28', '2019-06-25')
  ], ['id_', 'p', 'd1', 'd2'])

# convert d1, d2 to DateType() if they are StringType()
df2 = df.withColumn('d1', to_date('d1')).withColumn('d2', to_date('d2'))

df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- id_: long (nullable = true)
 |-- p: string (nullable = true)
 |-- d1: date (nullable = true)
 |-- d2: date (nullable = true)
```

### Create a referencing dataframe: df_drange

`df_drange` contains all distinct dates from d1 and d2,
plus a flag which is set to `1` when `df_drange.d1` is from `df.d2` (in the original df) and `0` otherwise. sort the dates and segement them into interval date ranges. retrieve the fields `d1`, `d2`, `flag`(d1 only) and convert them into proper DataType()

```
df_drange = df.select('id_', 'd1', lit(0).alias('flag')).union(df.select('id_', 'd2', lit(1))) \
    .groupby('id_') \
    .agg(array_sort(collect_set(concat('d1', lit('-'), 'flag'))).alias('dates')) \
    .withColumn('dates', expr("""
         explode(transform(sequence(0, size(dates)-2), i -> named_struct('d1', dates[i], 'd2', dates[i+1])))
       """)) \
    .selectExpr(
         'id_'
       , "to_date(substring_index(dates.d1, '-', 3)) as d1"
       , "to_date(substring_index(dates.d2, '-', 3)) as d2"
       , "boolean(substring_index(dates.d1, '-', -1)) as flag"
     )

df_drange.orderBy('id_','d1').show()
+---+----------+----------+-----+
|id_|        d1|        d2| flag|
+---+----------+----------+-----+
|  1|2018-09-26|2018-10-26|false|
|  2|2018-06-21|2018-06-27|false|
|  2|2018-06-27|2018-07-02|false|
|  2|2018-07-02|2018-07-07|false|
|  2|2018-07-07|2018-07-19| true|
|  2|2018-07-19|2019-02-27| true|
|  2|2019-02-27|2019-03-28| true|
|  2|2019-03-28|2019-06-25|false|
+---+----------+----------+-----+

df_drange.printSchema()
root
 |-- id_: long (nullable = true)
 |-- d1: date (nullable = true)
 |-- d2: date (nullable = true)
 |-- flag: boolean (nullable = true)
```

### Set up df1 with Join

Left join with the original df and for each id_ with any overlapping
between (*d1*, *d2*) of *df_dranges* and (*d1*, *d2*) of the *original df*. after
groupby(*id_*, *d1*, *d2*, *flag*) from *df_drange*, get the  array_join(collect_set(p), ' '):

```
df1 = broadcast(df_drange).join(
      df2
    , (df2.id_ == df_drange.id_) & (
            ((df2.d1 < df_drange.d2) & (df2.d2 > df_drange.d1)) 
          | ((df_drange.d1 == df_drange.d2) & df_drange.d1.between(df2.d1, df2.d2)) 
      )
    , how = 'left'
).groupby(df_drange.id_, df_drange.d1, df_drange.d2, df_drange.flag) \
 .agg(array_join(collect_set('p'), ' ').alias('q'))

df1.show()
+---+----------+----------+-----+-----+
|id_|        d1|        d2| flag|    q|
+---+----------+----------+-----+-----+
|  1|2018-09-26|2018-10-26|false|    A|
|  2|2018-06-21|2018-06-27|false|    B|
|  2|2018-06-27|2018-07-02|false|  C B|
|  2|2018-07-02|2018-07-07|false|C B A|
|  2|2018-07-07|2018-07-19| true|  B A|
|  2|2018-07-19|2019-02-27| true|    A|
|  2|2019-02-27|2019-03-28| true|     |
|  2|2019-03-28|2019-06-25|false|    A|
+---+----------+----------+-----+-----+
```

### Set up boundaries

For df1, if q == '', there is a gap, such rows should be removed.
the boundaries of each drange is defined based on flag, next_flag, next_d1
as discussed in the comments/chat. below is the pesudo-code to show the current logic how/when to adjust d1/d2:

```
flag = (if d1 is from original_d2) ? true : false
both next_d1 and next_flag defined on WindowSpec-w1

# for df1.d1: if flag is true, add 1 day, otherwise keep as-is
d1 = IF(flag, date_add(d1,1), d1)

# for df1.d2: keep as-is when there is gap with the next row or 
# the next_flag is true, else minus 1 day
d2 = IF((next_d1 != d2) or next_flag, d2, date_sub(d2,1))
```

Actual code:

```
# WindowSpec to calculate next_d1
w1 = Window.partitionBy('id_').orderBy('d1')

# filter out gaps and calculate next_d1 and the adjusted d1 and d2
df_new = df1.where('q!= ""') \
            .withColumn('next_d1', lead('d1').over(w1)) \
            .withColumn('next_flag', coalesce(lead('flag').over(w1), lit(True))) \
            .selectExpr(
                    'id_'
                  , 'q'
                  , 'IF(flag, date_add(d1,1), d1) AS d1'
                  , 'IF((next_d1 != d2) or next_flag, d2, date_sub(d2,1)) AS d2'
             )

df_new.show()
+---+-----+----------+----------+
|id_|    q|        d1|        d2|
+---+-----+----------+----------+
|  1|    A|2018-09-26|2018-10-26|
|  2|    B|2018-06-21|2018-06-26|
|  2|  C B|2018-06-27|2018-07-01|
|  2|C B A|2018-07-02|2018-07-07|
|  2|  B A|2018-07-08|2018-07-19|
|  2|    A|2018-07-20|2019-02-27|
|  2|    A|2019-03-28|2019-06-25|
+---+-----+----------+----------+
```

Comment: What if there is over lap among more than two rows?

Comment: how do you want to handle the overlapping for more then two rows, can you add some sample and expected result. I thought you added no more than two p-values in combination in your comments???

Comment: There may be overlap among more than two rows, with more than two p values

Comment: hmm, maybe you should really remove the **`not`** from your comment in the main post. `And please not the combination can be among more than two p values`. I will check this tomorrow. it's now too late at my time. however it would be better if you can add an example including such case and the expected result. this could save us time for guessing.

Comment: My apologies. I meant. Note. I will make the change to show more than two p values.

Comment: @SreeramTP, updated a completely new solution. one problem exists  for whether to adjust d1 or d2 when two date_ranges are connected. if it's important, please do add how you decide when to add/minus 1 day from which boundaries.

Comment: Give me some time to check and verify.

Comment: I haven't tested yet. But out of curiousity, did u test for some bigger data.? Do you expect the code to be fast enough for some 100-500 M rows.?

Comment: There is a small issue I can see straight away. I wanted to have the 3rd last row d2 to be 19th and also, the second row D1 should be 20th

Comment: @SreeramTP, I don't have big data to test. if your data contain only 4 columns plus 100-500 M rows, shoule not be a big problems. Certainly it also relies on your cluster and spark configurations.

Comment: @SreeramTP, that is what I mentioned in my post about the boundaries, when to adjust d1 and when to adjust d2. that could be very complex. In case the same date shows in both d1 and d2 of the original df, that would be an issue.

Comment: Let's assume for now same dates for D1 and D2 won't come for a specific row. That is for every row, D1 < D2

Comment: @SreeramTP I meant d2 could be the same as the next d1, or any d1 in a later dranges

Comment: I don't want my D1 to be changed. That's critical for my application. I totally understand the issue happenening. I ran in to a similar issue while designing the code myself.

Comment: I will needs a spec on how to define boundaries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199745/discussion-between-sreeram-tp-and-jxc).